# Probability of sum of 4 dice = 3

Tags: probability

You roll 4 dice and take the sum of the 3 lowest values. What is the probability that this sum is equal to 3?

My approach:

We need 3 dice to have exactly 1 on them to get the sum 3 and the 4th dice can have anything from 1-6 which happens with probability = $ \frac {1} {6^{3}} $

Now there are 4 possible ways to get such a combination = $ \frac {4} {216} $ = $ \frac {1} {54} $

Is the answer/approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henry's answer is correct. There are $21$ of the $6^4$ possible outcomes that result in a lowest-dice sum of 3. Your answer was $24$ out of $6^4$, erroneously counting 3 extra cases of success - where is the disconnect? The problem is that you are counting the case of all-1's four times instead of just once. Your mistake is in the step of claiming there are four possible ways to get a combination of three 1's and one other number - that's only true when the last number *isn't* a one. There is exactly one way to get all 1's, but you're counting it three extra times.

Answer (score 2):

I would have said:

- The probability the first three dice show $1$ and the last any of $2-6$ is $\frac{5}{6^4}$
- But there are other similar patterns with a different "other", so the probability three dice show $1$ and the other  $2-6$ is four times this, i.e. $\frac{20}{6^4}$
- And you need to add the probability all four dice show $1$ which is $\frac{1}{6^4}$
- Making the total probability of this outcome $\frac{21}{6^4}$

---

For what it is worth, this can be confirmed with a bruteforce count of the number of the $6^4=1296$ ways which give different totals for the lowest three:

```
 sumoflowthree  3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 
 ways          21  54  94 131 160 172 167 148 122  91  62  38  21  10   4   1
```